# aliasing self = super(...).__new__(...)? why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability, self, super

I wrote a [mixed number fraction class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35274/python-3-3-mixed-number-fractions-class) to extend and expand the functionality of the standard library `Fraction` class in order to accept anything that `Fraction` would and more: `Mixed('3 4/5')` == `Mixed(3,4,5)` == `Mixed(Fraction(19,5))` == `Fraction(19,5)`, etc. I've read a lot about `super` and I'm still not 100% sure I understand the what and why of this line in the `Fraction` class source `__new__` definition:

```
self = super(Fraction, cls).__new__(cls)
```

I suspect that it makes every reference to `self` point to and create a new instance of `Fraction` due to the class being immutable.  Is that what is happening and why?

Comment: `self` is a **local variable**; and the name is just a convention. Why do you think that every other reference to the instance will point something it should not?

Comment: Remember that `__new__` is the instance factory. It produces a new instance, but only if you call the proper `type.__new__` parent method, which returns the actual instance created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super(Fraction, cls).__new__` will look through the class MRO to look for the *next* `.__new__` method, starting the search one step on from the location of `Fraction`:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction.mro()
[<class 'fractions.Fraction'>, <class 'numbers.Rational'>, <class 'numbers.Real'>, <class 'numbers.Complex'>, <class 'numbers.Number'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So it'll look at all the other classes to see where the next `__new__` is defined, the code then calls that. Ultimately, that'll be `object.__new__`, where Python's C code creates the actual C structures that form the number object:

```
>>> for cls in Fraction.mro()[1:]:
...     if '__new__' in cls.__dict__:
...         print(cls)
... 
<class 'object'>
```

The stated *purpose* of the `__new__` method is to create a new instance. And because numbers are indeed immutable, that is the point where you want to hook in to be able to customize how the instance is created, because once it exists, it cannot be altered anymore.

The name `self` is just a local name.  It matches the *convention* used by methods, but `__new__` is not an ordinary bound method as there is nothing to bind *to* when creating a new instance. You can replace that name throughout the function with something entirely different (`instance`, `this_new_object_we_just_created`, etc.) and the code would still work the same. `self` in *other* functions is not affected by it.

As it happens, `Fraction` instances **are** mutable; the class defines `_numerator` and `_denominator` slots, which can still be rebound after the instance has been created. The `Fraction.__new__()` factory method actually does this; it assigns new values to those attributes. After adjusting these attributes, `self` is returned, thus fulfilling the contract of the `__new__` method, to return the new instance.

In principle, setting the `_numerator` and `_denominator` attributes could all have been done in an `__init__` method too. The Python developers have however decided to stick to the convention for immutable types as the class is **meant** to be treated as immutable:

```
>>> fraction = Fraction(3, 4)
>>> fraction.numerator
3
>>> fraction.numerator = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> fraction._numerator = 4
>>> fraction.numerator
4
```

but as you can see, if you know about the mutable attributes, you can still mutate the instance from the outside.

Comment: Aha.  I didn't realize that, as Martijn Pieters commented above, `__new__` in the child must call the proper `__new__` of the parent.  Is it then correct to assume that if, for example, an intervening class in the hierarchy had defined a `__new__` method, the call still find its way to `object.__new__`?  Or in other words, all properly written `__new__` calls eventually find their way up the hierarchy to `object.__new__`?

Comment: @JB0x2D1: `super(Fraction, cls).__new__` would find *that* method before finding `object.__new__`, and it is up to *that* method to return an instance. If it chooses to do so by calling `object.__new__` or use `super()` or whatever, that is up to that method.

Comment: @JB0x2D1: It could instead use a cache of objects, not *always* call `object.__new__` but instead returning existing instances. Python does this for small integers, for example, a process called 'interning' to speed up common comparison operations and reduce the memory footprint.